# JSON's application/json header wont work on chrome/IE while works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending an ajax request to pull list of web services and then show them in table later on. However, the code workds on Firefox correctly but not on chorome and IE.

**AJAX REQUEST:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://dev.ragld.com/services/',
   method: 'GET',
   accept: 'application/json',
   beforeSend: setHeader,
   async: false, 
   success: function(data){  
       var servicesObj = $.parseJSON(data);

       $.each(servicesObj, function(i, serviceItem){
           alert(serviceItem.name);
       });
   }
});

//function to setup header information
function setHeader(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json'); 
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "OS-ONS-bar",
        "type": "RelationshipService",
        "endpoint": "http://dev.ragld.com/services/bar/"
    },
    {
        "name": "OS-ONS-sameAs",
        "type": "RelationshipService",
        "endpoint": "http://dev.ragld.com/services/sameas/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Maths Service 2",
        "type": "ArithmeticService",
        "endpoint": "http://dev.ragld.com/services/arithmetic/"
    }
]
```

**ERROR I get in chrome with above code:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
$.ajax.success admin.php:157
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) admin.php:148
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

**PROBLEMS:**

1. This works fine on Firefox but not on Chrome and IE.
2. Now, if I remove this `$.parseJSON`, then it will work on chrome but NOT in firefox/IE

PS: ajax request is made to a different server and this code is on different. Anyone please advise solution that works on all browsers???

**EDIT1:**
Looks like chrome automatically parse it or getting the json header, whereas, in firefox we need to parse it explicitly usin parseJSON??? any ideas?

**EDIT2 (console.log from FireFox):**

```
[{"name":"OS-ONS-bar","type":"RelationshipService","endpoint":"http:\/\/dev.ragld.com\/services\/bar\/"},{"name":"OS-ONS-sameAs","type":"RelationshipService","endpoint":"http:\/\/dev.ragld.com\/services\/sameas\/"},{"name":"Maths Service 2","type":"ArithmeticService","endpoint":"http:\/\/dev.ragld.com\/services\/arithmetic\/"}]
```

**console.log from Chrome:**
[image]

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean by this?  Do you see a response from the server in IE and Chrome, but nothing is rendered?  Do you see an error?

Comment: yes just added the error I get in chrome

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` in your success callback function to debug the response.

Comment: @Stefan: It display correct records with `parseJSON` when I check it on Firefox but shows same error on chrome.

Comment: I believe for some reasons, chrome isn't happy with parsing JSON again using the parseJSON function.

Comment: Don´t parse the response, just view it with `console.log(data)` and add the output from both your browsers to your post/question.

Comment: @Stefan: I have now added both the outputs. Hope this will help?

Comment: Looks like Firefox outputs a `string` while Chrome ouputs an `Object array`. Try; `var servicesObj = (typeof(data) === 'string') ? $.parseJSON(data) : data;`.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the [ajax option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `dataType` as 'json'. Otherwise jQuery will have to guess what data type it should return and you might get various results.

> **DataType**
>
> If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME
> type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON
> will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script,
> and anything else will be returned as a string).

View my [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXX9H/) that works in FF, IE and Chrome.

You should inspect the XHR response and make sure that your service is actually returning JSON.

Comment: This won't help.. You are right, problem lies with the return type of the data. But why is different type returned on different browsers?? Any idea?

Comment: Your previous solution worked to check the typeof returned data and retrieve accordingly. It now works on both firefox and chrome but still no luck with IE.
Is there not any solution to return one type of data back?